# How to sum() values in mySQL that are related to a specific ID?

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I want to show in a single table all payments made by students.
Students can belong to more than one course, so I would need to know the sum of payments that belongs to each course.

```
I've tried this:

SELECT      usuarios.userID, usuarios.userEmail, usuarios.docVerificada, 
            pagos.cursoID, pagos.pagoMonto,
            SUM(pagos.pagoMonto)

FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN pagos
ON usuarios.userID = pagos.userID

WHERE pagos.estadoPago = 1

GROUP BY usuarios.userEmail
```

**But it outputs all payments, one for each row, but I want to group them according to their cursoID.**

### These are the tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE pagos (
    pagoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    cursoID int null,
    estadoPago int(1) not null DEFAULT '0'
    pagoMonto int null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    userID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userEmail char(50) null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the actual output that I get:
[image]

And these are the results without any grouping or sum:
[image]

The intended results would be:

> UserID 16 -- cursoID 15 -- payments total 23
>
> UserID 16 -- cursoID 16 -- payments total 77 (it should sum only 24,
>   26 and 27)

and so on...

Comment: `I want to group them according to their cursoID` -- Have you tried adding `cursoID` to the `group by` clause then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include `pagos.cursoID` in `Group By` in your query

```
SELECT      
    usuarios.userID, usuarios.userEmail, usuarios.docVerificada, 
    pagos.cursoID, pagos.pagoMonto, SUM(pagos.pagoMonto) as Total
FROM 
   usuarios 
INNER JOIN 
   pagos
ON 
   usuarios.userID = pagos.userID
WHERE 
    pagos.estadoPago = 1
GROUP BY 
    usuarios.userID, pagos.cursoID
```